# Copy managed disk snapshots to a different region from the azure command line

Tags: azure

I am trying to copy a managed disk snapshot to different region using the Azure command line and it fails with the following error - "The entity was not found"

Here is the command I am using
az snapshot create --resource-group test-azstdsouthcentral --name testcopy3 --location WestUS2 --source /subscriptions/xxx/resourceG
roups/test-azstdsouthcentral/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/testcopy

Is it supported to copy a managed disk snapshot to a separate region?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it supported to copy a managed disk snapshot to a separate region?

You **can't** create snapshot to different region.

But you can create snapshot to the same region, then **copy the snapshot as VHD to a storage account in different region**, then create a managed disk from a VHD.

Sample script:

```
#Provide the subscription Id where snapshot is created
subscriptionId=dd80b94e-0463-4a65-8d04-c94f403879dc

#Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot is created
resourceGroupName=myResourceGroupName

#Provide the snapshot name 
snapshotName=mySnapshotName

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
sasExpiryDuration=3600

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the snapshot. 
storageAccountName=mystorageaccountname

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded snapshot will be stored
storageContainerName=mystoragecontainername

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy snapshot. 
storageAccountKey=mystorageaccountkey

#Provide the name of the VHD file to which snapshot will be copied.
destinationVHDFileName=myvhdfilename

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas
```

More information about export/copy managed snapshots as VHD to a storage account in different region, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-account).

More information about create a managed disk from a VHD, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-create-managed-disk-from-vhd?toc=%2Fcli%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)